# Reverse a string in KIBANA/painless

Tags: elasticsearch-painless

I'm not able to reverse a string in KIBANA/painless (section: scripted fields)

```
def foo = ('dlroW olleH');
return foo.reverse();
```

I expect the output of "Hello World", but KIBANA sais "No results found".
If i do a "return foo;" it works well - on every outputline "dlroW olleH" is shown.

Can anyone give me a hint, where the problem is?

EDIT: kibana 5.6, regexp for painless is disabled

Comment: Have you tried `foo.reverse();` on its own, followed by `return foo` ?

Comment: yes, i tried this as well. same problem. i"ll check kibana 6 tomorrow, maybe it's a 5.x problem or not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.reverse()` isn't a listed method to operate on a `String` object <sup>[[1]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference.html#painless-api-reference-String)</sup>; it's available to operate a `StringBuffer` object. <sup>[[2]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference.html#painless-api-reference-StringBuffer)</sup>

You can make a `StringBuffer` and call `reverse` on it.

```
StringBuffer foo = new StringBuffer('dlroW olleH');
foo.reverse();
return foo.toString();
```